# Corona Timer and memory issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Say I am using timer in my game for example

```
 timer.performWithDelay(1000, function() end, 1)
```

Is it necessary that I should assign this to an local variable and cancel after its use i.e,

```
 local timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(1000, function() end, 1)
 timer.cancel(timerVar) 
 timerVar = nil
```

Help me with this .....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect the timer to be cancelled, you don't have to store it's reference. But I also recommend to not use anonymous function in timer. It's harder to debug then, because you'll not know the name of a function if it's throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

the cancel() method is for stopping and removing the timer before it finishes. There's no need to call it after the timer is done.

Answer (score 0):

i think you try this below.

```
local timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(1000, function(e)
timer.cancel(e.source) 
e.source = nil
end, 1)
```